# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, noclassdeffounderror, rad

I am using Spring in my Jar file to get the properties from a properties file. I am getting output when I try from my RAD(eclipse). But when I deploy my jar file in server, I keep getting this error. Do I need to include any other XML file ?

The error occurs when I get the application context.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://xml.westfieldgrp.com/public/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://xml.westfieldgrp.com/public/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://xml.westfieldgrp.com/public/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd" >    
    <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/config/devint/nimo.properties"/>
    </bean>  
    <bean id="nimoConfigurationBean" scope="singleton"
        class="com.westfieldgrp.filenet.env.NimoConfigurationBean">
        <property name="serviceUser" value="${env.user}" />
        <property name="servicePass" value="${env.pass}" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Call in Java:

```
public class AddEnvProperty {

    public String envType(String propertyValue) {   
        String returnValue = "";

        AddEnvProperty envProps = new AddEnvProperty();
        NimoConfigurationBean nimoConfigurationBean = envProps.getConfig();

        PluginLogger logger = new PluginLogger(new ResponceFilterPlugin());
        logger.logDebug(this, "envType", "Getting Property Value" + propertyValue);
        try {

             if (propertyValue == "USER") {
                returnValue = nimoConfigurationBean.getServiceUser();
            } else if (propertyValue == "PASS") {
                returnValue = nimoConfigurationBean.getServicePass();
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            logger.logError(this, "envType", "NullPointerException:", ex);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.logError(this, "envType", "NullPointerException:", ex);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private NimoConfigurationBean getConfig() {
        ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        NimoConfigurationBean obj = (NimoConfigurationBean) context.getBean("nimoConfigurationBean");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Getter, setter methods in NimoConfigurationBean.java

Comment: You likely have a version mismatch with multiple versions of that class in your classpath.

Comment: Class-Path: ./lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar ./lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/src_common.jar ./xml/* ./xml/config/xml/applicationContext.xml ./xml/config/xml/environmentContext.xml ./xml/config/xml/nimo-context.xml

Comment: I am using only spring 3.0.1 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have that dependency in ur pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

(x.x.x : to be modified)

if you aren't using maven :
check the jar "`spring-context-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar`" into your build path

Comment: The code is working from my rad but giving error when deployed as JAR

Comment: Are you sure that the jar `spring-context-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar` is deployed also within your jar?

Comment: I have included it in my manifest.mf in class path Class-Path: ./lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar ./lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar ./lib/src_common.jar ./xml/* ./xml/config/xml/applicationContext.xml ./xml/config/xml/environmentContext.xml ./xml/config/xml/nimo-context.xml